# In php saving all $_GET variables in a session variable and make them accessible trough $_GET again

Tags: php

I would like to save all `$_GET` variables in a session variable and make them accessible trough `$_GET` again later on.

Some pseudo code / algoritm

page1.php send form with a field as `<form action="page1.php" method="get"><input type="text" value="banan" name="apa">`

page2.php save all `$_GET` variables

page3.php Set back all get-variables as in page2.php so the first variable is accessible trough `$_GET['apa']`

is this possible?

Comment: Useful for prototyping to set the input dynamically when for example having a form running in steps when the data is relevant in complete steps/adding new fields simply. Of course this isn't solid for other than prototyping, and there is faster ways for wireframe mockup prototyping today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't do this.**  But to save:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION["GET"] = $_GET;

?>
```

and to retrieve:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_GET = $_SESSION["GET"];

?>
```

I think the real problem here is that you have a goal you want to accomplish and you *think* this is the right way of achieving that goal.  It's not; there is most assuredly a better way of accomplishing the end result you want.  But you have to tell us what that end result is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but I am not sure why one would want to do that. Why not just read the data from `$_SESSION` rather than `$_GET` so as to not confuse session data with data that is actually passed as parameter to the page you are on.